# http 500 servlet with io exception - left in a limbo

Tags: java, http, tomcat, ioexception, http-error

I am uploading a file through a servlet onto my server. 
It has been working fine all along until this afternoon, when all of a sudden I started getting the

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8282
```

I have been using tomcat 7 for the application and was working fine since long.
I am not sure what crashed within the server or where exactly the issue is happening.

I tried:

1. Changing different ports
2. Clean, delete and use different servers ( Vfabric)
3. Added `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` to the system variables.
4. Uninstalled and reinstalled tomcat.
5. Tried restarting the systems to see if there are any open/daemon threads hanging.
6. Increased the max thread size in the server.xml in the tomcat folder.

I could not come across other possible feasible options to resolve the issue. Please suggest and provide insight if possible.

Below is the code from my application : (Client-side code):

```
private URLConnection getServletConnection() throws MalformedURLException,
            IOException {

        // Config
        servletConnection.setDoInput(true);
        servletConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        servletConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        servletConnection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
        servletConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        servletConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + this.boundary);
        servletConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        servletConnection.connect();
        return servletConnection;
    }

    private boolean onSendData(String fileEntry) {
        try {
            // Send data to the servlet
            HttpURLConnection servletConnection = (HttpURLConnection) getServletConnection();
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                    servletConnection.getOutputStream());
            final FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
            ...
            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                    + lineEnd);


            // Receive result from servlet
            InputStream inputStream = servletConnection.getInputStream();
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(
                    inputStream);
            String result = (String) objectInputStream.readObject();

            objectInputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();
            fileInputStream.close();

        } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException mue) {
            mue.printStackTrace();
            System.out
                    .println("Invalid serlvetUrl, error: " + mue.getMessage());
            errorLabel.setText(mue.getMessage());
        } catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Couldn't open a URLConnection, error: "
                    + ioe.getMessage());
            errorLabel.setText(ioe.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception caught, error: " + e.getMessage());
            errorLabel.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
        return fileUploaded;
    }
```

And this is the error I am seeing (WHEN I RUN THE CODE AS AN APPLET IN MY IDE ):

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8282/UploadFile/upload
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at com.FileUpload.onSendData(FileUpload.java:317)
    ... 4 more
```

Strangely, when I am running this on a web-browser(RUNNING AS A SIGNED JAR FILE), I see the following error in the java console (This is an applet).

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
   Couldn't open a URLConnection, error: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: I just edited and added the server side code. The exception I posted is the exception I am seeing in my IDE console.

Comment: Not packaged and deployed correctly.  Is this in a WAR file?

Comment: This is a signed applet in a jar file. I was able to run it correctly since few days and even today, until few hours ago. I use the jar to deploy onto the browser. In my IDE, I just run the project as an applet.

Comment: Can you find the server-side exception?  Have a look in tomcat/logs/catalina.out or somewhere like that.

Comment: Sure, I have seen it earlier, and it was empty. I will try to look for it again.

Comment: @PaulHicks : I saw this in the catalina file, but I would not think this would be a concern : INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;;.

Comment: Also, in the tomcat-stdout file , 2014-02-12 20:22:53 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized is logged. I'm not sure if this would mean anything.

Comment: No they don't look interesting.  Maybe the expected service isn't running at the expected address, and something else is serving your request.

Comment: @duffymo : You were right ! I happen to delete a jar that was used by the servlet. Added the jar back in and am able to get it working again.

Comment: Nice work.  Good job.